# Google Sheets Query, filtering with a range of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to query data by checking if the data_range's column C (invoice#) matches this tab any value in column B (invoice#), while this tab column B will have variable data size ( copy from another list, it can be 2 values or 3 values or 10 values or etc. ).

Does anyone know how to achieve it?
I tried

> =QUERY('data'!A2:X,"SELECT * WHERE C IN '"&B3:B&"'", true)

but failed. Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user two times.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY doesn't support the full set of SQL clauses in the select string so you can't use IN to evaluate multiple WHEREs. You can get the same result by using JOIN & MATCHES as I've outlined in this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76029347/google-query-language-seems-to-lack-an-equivalent-to-sqls-in/76029538#76029538

Comment: I see, thanks for helping!